# Exclude specific color/colors from colormap in groupby plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Is there is any parameter or function that will help me to exclude for example **yellow** color from chosen colormap?

**MWE**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index=pd.date_range('2011-1-1 00:00:00', '2011-12-31 23:50:00', freq='1h')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),3).cumsum(axis=0),columns=['A','B','C'],index=index)

df2 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.month)

for key, group in df2:
    group.plot(colormap='gnuplot')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice the colormap like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

index=pd.date_range('2011-1-1 00:00:00', '2011-12-31 23:50:00', freq='1h')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),3).cumsum(axis=0),columns=['A','B','C'],index=index)

df2 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
'''
you can define the slize of the colormap in the range from 0 to 1
by calling np.linspace I created three colors ranging from 0 to 70 % 
of the colors from the chosen colormap. The first two arguments 
define the slize of the colormap, the last one defines the number
of colors'''
cm = plt.cm.gnuplot(np.linspace(0,0.7,3))
for i, item in enumerate(df2):
    key, group = item
    group.plot(color=cm)
```

Comment: would you be able to briefly explain what are the numbers in `np.linspace(0,0.7,3)`